# How to improve performance of writing DB data to CSV

Tags: java, csv, resultset

I have the following code to read data from oracle database and write into csv file. I used OpenCSV jar to write. It takes 230 seconds to write 1MB data. Is there any other way to increase the performance?

```
springJdbcTemplate.query(query,new ResultSetExtractor<ResultSet>(){

            @Override
            public ResultSet extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                    DataAccessException {
                try {
                    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:/csv/Sample.csv"), ';');
                    writer.writeAll(rs, true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception -> "+e);
                }

                return rs;
            }});
```

Comment: can you share the code of csvwriter?

Comment: It is more likely the time is taken extracting the data.  How longer does it take to extract all the data, without writing it?

Comment: @Hirak CSVWriter is a class in OpenCSV jar. It is not my customized class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It is taking 7 seconds without writing.

Comment: @Samurai - *"It is taking 7 seconds without writing"* ... Are you reading the resultset, or just closing it.

Comment: I just added while(rs.next()){ } inside the try. It is taking 247 seconds. Actual csv size is 1200KB..

Comment: I too tried out the code. It shows around 7-8 seconds to execute query. But this 7-8 seconds shows time to fetch first 50 records. When I executed the same query on SQL Developer and tried to fetch the last record(total 500K records approx), it took around 20 minutes. So the timelog to execute query is for fetching first 50 records only.  Hence, data extraction is taking significant time rather than writing.

Answer (score 2):

> It is taking 7 seconds without writing.

I can't image why the CSVWriter is so slow unless it need buffering.

Can you try

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(
                   new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/csv/Sample.csv")), ';');
```

and add

```
writer.close();
```

or use Java 7+

```
try(CSVWriter writer = ...) {
```

---

try this

```
import java.io.*;

public class DumbCSVWriter {
    private final Writer writer;
    private final String sep;

    public DumbCSVWriter(Writer writer, String sep) {
        this.sep = sep;
        this.writer = writer instanceof BufferedWriter ? writer : new BufferedWriter(writer);
    }

    public void addRow(Object... values) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
            print(values[i]);
            writer.write(sep);
        }
        if (values.length > 0)
            print(values[values.length - 1]);
        writer.write("\n");
    }

    private void print(Object value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) return;
        String str = value.toString();
        if (str.contains(sep) || str.contains("\"") || str.contains("\n")) {
            str = '"' + str.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
        }
        writer.write(str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        File file = new File("/tmp/deleteme");
        DumbCSVWriter writer = new DumbCSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ";");
        String[] words = "hello,0123456789,has a;semi-colon,has a \"quote".split(",");
        for (int i = 0; file.length() < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
            writer.addRow(words);
        }
        writer.close();
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Time tow rite 1 MB %.3f%n", time / 1e9);
    }

    private void close() throws IOException {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

prints

Time to write 1 MB 0.307

Comment: BufferedWriter reduced 10 seconds. Still taking more time.

Comment: @Samurai can you performance profile it.  I can't imagine why it would take more than a second to write 1 MB of CSV data.

Comment: The problem is with reading data from DB. For simple while(rs.next()){ } inside the try is taking 247 seconds for 1200KB data.

Comment: @Samurai You need to optimise you query. Do you need to add Indexing?

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard way of doing it, there's nothing wrong with your code; the only suggestion I'd have about your code is to use BufferedWriter or OutputStreamWriter like:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/csv/Sample.csv"))
```

It may help just a little bit, but 230 seconds is not about writing a 1MB CSV file that's got to be about your database connection. Try just looping through the result set without writing to a file, I bet you'd get the same time.
Try setting the fetchSize for your statement (Statement or PreparedStatement) like

```
stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
```

This can significantly reduce the result set fetching time.